# What does 'I'm not about caring' mean?

Tags: prepositions

I was watching 'Suits'. I encountered this

> Mike: This woman had her life ripped apart. You don’t even care?
>   Harvey: ***I’m not about caring. I’m about winning.***
>   Mike: Why can’t you be about both?

I could understand what Harvey says : I'm not interested in caring. I'm interested in winning. (That is what I understand)

I don't exactly understand about 'about' in this sentence.

Plus, you can also find out **be about** in the next sentence.

What does 'I'm about noun' mean?

Could I get more examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your interpretation, "I'm not interested in caring; I'm interested in winning," is correct.

And you could extend that to the third line: "why can't you be about both" is equivalent to "why can't you be interested in both."

See [definitions 3 and 4c of the preposition form here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/about).

> 3 engaged in
>
> 4c fundamentally concerned with or directed toward

You can see it in conversations like this:

> I love decorating for the holidays.
>
> Me too.  I'm all about that.

Note that "I'm about something" (and also "I'm all about something") are still considered somewhat slang; I wouldn't use them in formal written language.  "I'm all about that" = I enjoy it highly, it's my primary goal or focus, it's what I'm most concerned about, it's a defining feature of my personality or identity.